# Go back to the original number after the sum of values ​between two lists

Tags: python, list, operation

I wrote this code to sum a number and its reverse:

```
    #sum the multiple of the first number and its reversed

    zipped_lists = zip(primo, reversedList)
    res = [x + y for (x, y) in zipped_lists]
    print (res)

    #search common values in "res" and "secondo"

    common_list = set(res).intersection(secondo)
```

Now that I isolated significant numbers, I need to return to the original number listed in `primo`. I've no idea how to do that. Please, help me :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of `x` against its corresponding value of `x + y`. Instead of checking for the presence in `secondo` after you create `res`, you could do the filtering in a single comprehension.

```
res = [
    x
    for x, y in zip(primo, reversedList)
    if (x + y) in secondo
]
```

Comment: Writing that, it doesn't work:

Comment: ```#sum the multiple of the first number and its reversed

 zipped_lists = zip(primo, reversedList)
 res = [x + y for (x, y) in zipped_lists]
 print (res)

 #search common values in "res" and "secondo"

 res = [
    x
    for x, y in zip(primo, reversedList)
    if (x + y) in secondo
    ]

 print()
 print()

 if len(res) == 0:
  print ("No results found")
 else:
  print ("The numbers are: ", res)```

Comment: @AndreaValsesia could you provide an example of `primo`, `secondo` and `reversedList` where this fails?

Comment: If there aren't matches, the script works. But, when there are common values, the script interrupts after printing ```reversedList```